# Rooting Honor View 10 WITHOUT unlocking Bootloader?

Tags: systemless-root

Does anyone know if it's possible to root the Honor View 10 without unlocking the Bootloader first? Huawei no longer provide Bootloader unlock codes, but I can't work out if the Honor View 10 can simply be rooted without flashing anything, i.e. as a separate and distinct process.... If so, does anybody have/know of a procedure for this? ....(Lots of conflicting opinions on this!)....Cheers, River

Comment: You need to get the unlock code with GSM Multi Hub and then Unlock the bootloader... Then flash TWRP with Fastboot & Then root with Magisk.zip.... Found Full Software on Google Drive here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B41hcbd6Ki6ocENEcmhxbEh0dlU/view   & Found Guide for usage here... https://erdentec.com/huawei-bootloader-unlocker-tools/#5_Huawei_Code_Calculator

Comment: Buy an unlock code somewhere. Don't even think about rooting modern phones with exploits.

Comment: Have already tried to buy a Bootloader code, but it seems it's just impossible now...Even 'funkyhuawei' can no longer supply for the extortionate price of $155